# How to get the unique values in DVWP using XSLT

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt

My requirement is to get the unique values from the list in DVWP Web Part using XSL.

Let's say i have following values in my list (10,10,20,30) and i need to show as (10,20,30).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance 
Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little on the old side but I just noticed it when I was searching for something else and I realized that I had already solved this one for myself so here goes!

Find the line in your code that says

```
xsl:variable name="Rows"
```

and change the select parameter to read

```
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(@yourfieldName=preceding-sibling::Row/@yourfieldname)]
```

That worked for me anyways! Happy sharepointing!